# Declaration of differents types of extern variables in C

Tags: c, pointers, declaration, extern

I have a doubt about declaration of external variables. I'm working in a project that is already working, and it is like below (it is an example based in the real program):

## file1.h

```
   #include "mystruct.h"
   extern long    a ;
   extern strc_1  s ;
   extern STRC_2  *ss;
```

In my main program I have

## main.c

```
  #include "file1.h"
  long    a ;
  strc_1  s ;

  main()
  {
     a = 10;
     s.variableX = 10;
     s.variableY = 50;

     ss.J = 50;
     ss.J = 250;         
  }
```

So, my question is: Why does not the pointer 'ss' need to be declared in the main program? And why does it work? I mean, the variables 'a' and 'strc_1' were declared in the main program because I use them, however,  I use 'ss' but I did not declared it in the main program.

Comment: This won't compile. `ss.J` is invalid as `ss` is a pointer (and thus not a structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long    a ;
strc_1  s ;
```

These in `main.c` are called **definitions**, not **declarations**. (To be precise, all definitions are also declarations).

The reason you don't have to define `ss` is because it's defined in some other source file. As long as the declaration of `ss` (which is in `header1.h`) can be seen, it will compile fine.